# Slim json blank when response has special characters

Tags: php, json, utf-8, slim

So i'm building a simple api but i have some problems.

Here's my code:

```
$this->get('/', function(Request $request, Response $response) use($conn) {
        $qb = $conn->createQueryBuilder();
        $result = $qb->select('*')
            ->from('cities')
            ->execute()
            ->fetchAll();
      $response = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json', 'charset=utf-8');
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($result));
        return $response;
    });
```

Everytime json response have a special character or a word like "São Paulo", json response its just blank(with no errors). Found this when i removed the ã, and the response was ok. How can i solve this?

Comment: Look at your error log.

Comment: Why don't you just use `withJson()` , it automatically sets the `Content-Type` to `application/json;charset=utf-8` [from docs](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html#returning-json)